# How to write in Verdana or Century Gothic Font in a LaTex file

Tags: fonts

I have a report to write in Verdana or Century Gothic. It's my second report in LaTex and I do not know how to change the font. Is there Verdana or Century Gothic avalaible in LaTex ? if yes, how to use it ? I use Overleaf or TexWorks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Overleaf all you need to do is change the compiler to LuaLaTex or XeLaTex and then add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
```